# How can I copy many large hi-res photos directly from iPad to cloud storage via WiFi and then manage them?

Tags: ipad, wifi, photos, network

What's a good method to copy lots of high resolution photos from my iPad using WiFi *directly*  to some sort of cloud server without having to use a Windows or Mac computer as an intermediary? Plus, once they're in the cloud, I'd like to delete the originals from the iPad and then use the iPad to organize/manage the photos on the cloud server: sort them into folders, rename them, and view them, etc.

I think I can use Dropbox for much of this but is there anything more efficient for managing lots of high-res photos? I think iPhoto and Adobe Revel are only useful if your photo library is based on a desktop computer - I want to avoid that step.

Comment: Looks like maybe a combination of DropBox and CameraSync would work well?  http://homegrownsw.com/camerasync/ Would other options make more sense?

Comment: Looks like another iOS app that would work is PhotoSync http://www.photosync-app.com/photosync/en/features.html

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that exactly what the [Photo Stream Feature](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html) is good for? It snycs all images directly into the iCloud. Yes it would also sync them to all devices, but I guess that's optional.

Comment: PhotoStream is a way of automating importing to multiple devices. Nothing is saved "in the Cloud". After 1,000 images or 30 days, which ever comes first, material is deleted.

Comment: Ok, in this case it's definitely not the right choice to save photos to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

www.picasaweb.com

It is a google service, so if you already have gmail then you already have an account.  I'm not sure if its native on apple devices, but there should be apps for ipad/iphone which do a lot of what you're asking.

Comment: I have an account with Picasaweb, but I don't know any good way to transfer lots of pictures from the iPad to Picasaweb directly. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Adobe Revel requires your library to be based on a desktop computer?

"Yes. Adobe Revel is virtually the same app on your iPad, iPhone, and Mac. You get the same experience and the same photo editing tools on all your Apple devices, which makes learning easy. So pick up any device you want and start making your photos look their best."